# aMerge two dicts, add items in duplicate keys, add keys and items when there is no duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this working code, but wondering if i can make it faster, or more pythonic.

I have two dicts that i want to merge into one. If there are duplicate keys, items in said key are compared and non duplicates added. If there exists a unique key in either list, the key with items are added.

Like this:

```
dict1 = {'name': ['chris','pablo','dora'], 'animal': ['horse','cat']}
dict2 = {'name': ['chris','mark'], 'car': ['toyota','ford']}

merge these and get this output

dict3 = {'name':['chris','pablo,'dora','mark'], 'animal': ['horse','cat'],
'car': ['toyota','ford']}
```

this code does the trick:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'name': ['chris','pablo','dora'], 'animal': ['horse','cat']}
dict2 = {'name': ['chris','mark'], 'car': ['toyota','ford']}
dd = defaultdict(list)

for key1 in dict1:
    for key2 in dict2:
        if key1 == key2:
            dict1Keylist = list(dict1[key1])
            Dict2Keylist = list(dict2[key2])
            third = list(set(dict1Keylist) | set(Dict2Keylist))
            dd[key1] = third
keys1 = list(dict1.keys())
keys2 = list(dict2.keys())
for key in keys1:
    if key not in keys2:
        dict1Keylist = list(dict1.get(key))
        dd[key] = dict1Keylist



for key in keys2:
    if key not in keys1:
        dict2Keylist = list(dict2.get(key))
        dd[key] = dict2Keylist


print(dd)
```

and generetes this output:

> defaultdict(, {'name': ['mark', 'dora', 'pablo',
>   'chris'], 'animal': ['horse', 'cat'], 'car': ['toyota', 'ford']})

can i improve this code to make it more pythonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a *dictionary comprehension* that takes the union of keys from both dicts using the `|` operator, merges the values by doing a list addition and removes duplicates by building a set from the merged values:

```
d = {k: list(set(dict1.get(k, []) + dict2.get(k, []))) 
                                  for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}

print(d)
# {'animal': ['horse', 'cat'], 'name': ['chris', 'pablo', 'mark', 'dora'], 'car': ['ford', 'toyota']}
```

`dict.get` is used to return an empty list if the dict does not contain a certain key.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)

for key in dict1:
    result[key].update(dict1[key])

for key in dict2:
    result[key].update(dict2[key])

for key in result:
    result[key] = list(result[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'name': ['chris','pablo','dora'], 'animal': ['horse','cat']}
dict2 = {'name': ['chris','mark'], 'car': ['toyota','ford']}

# if you have many dicts to merge, put them in a list
dict_to_merge = [dict1, dict2]

# use set as facotry function to avoid duplicate items
result = defaultdict(set)

# collect all keys
keys = set()
for di in dict_to_merge:
    di.update(di.keys())
# then collect all items
for key in keys:
    for di in dict_to_merge:
        result[key].update(di.get(key))
        # dict.get(key) will not raise KeyError
        # if key isn't in dict, return None instead.
```